# React performance - DOM styling and component rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, browser

Can someone please explain what happens when I change the CSS class of a React component?

Let's say I have this code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
const Comp = props => {
    const [class, setClass] = useState('visible')
    if (props.hide) {
        setClass('hidden');
    }
    return (<p className={class}>some text</p>)
}
```

My understanding of the process is this one:

1. Something in the parent component triggers a state change determining the Comp child to be called with property "hide" set to true
2. React will reconstruct the virtual DOM and the resulting html node of Comp will have the class set to "hidden"
3. React will update the DOM
4. Browser will render the DOM and apply the new styling

Am I correct?
Some related questions:

a. If the applied CSS class is just hiding the component, wouldn't be more efficient just to apply some conditional logic inside React parent component and don't display it at all?

b. If applying styling to html node just triggers the browser's painting method, why should we link CSS classes to the app state, thus triggering a full rendering? For me it seems inefficient.

Comment: For very few cases, like showing or hiding the component, you can put conditional logic. For genuine styling related changes, you'll have to update styles only.

Comment: A visibile:hidden component is still mounted, however a non-rendered component will be unmounted from React v-dom too and will have it's corresponding life-cycle methods invoked as well. So some considerations are needed depending on the complexity of the component as well.